# How to add a notification to a MediaPlayer Service?

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer, android-notifications

I have a working MediaPlayer app. The MainActivity (MyListActivity.java) binds itself to a Service (MediaService.java). The Service plays the music in the background.

I would like to know a way to add a notification so the user can control the tracks through it. I am using an Interface to pass the data from the Service to the Activity.

I have no clue where to start. I tried the Notifications tutorial on the [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html), but I don't know how to add buttons and I cannot find a decent tutorial for `RemoteViews`.

This is what I have for my notification.

> MediaService.java

```
    play(Track track) {
        ...
        showNotification(track);
    }

    showNoticiation(Track track){
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.dj_plink_avatar)
                .setContentTitle(track.getTitle())
                .setContentText(track.getGenre());

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MyListActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MyListActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);

        PendingIntent pIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(pIntent);

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context
                .NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(notificationID, builder.build());
    }
```

PS: Api 15 minimum please :)

Comment: try this ..if you find it useful...

https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/using-android-media-style-notifications-with-media-session-controls/165

Comment: That's for api 21+ right?  I would like something that supports at least api 15

Comment: @AftabHussain - there's a compat version of everything mentioned there

Comment: @ianhanniballake on the link Lovish posted? I didn't see a compat version :/

Comment: @AftabHussain - adding the word Compat at the end of each class works for me. Perhaps you're using the `v4.app.NotificationCompat`? `NotificationCompat.MediaStyle` requires `v7.app.NotificationCompat` (which is part of AppCompat).

Comment: Oh, I haven't tried that. Thanks! I will try it asap :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NotificationCompat.MediaStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat.MediaStyle.html), part of [AppCompat](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat), does all of the styling required and works back to API 7.

You'll still need to build your own `PendingIntent`s for each action, but those can be done any way that makes sense. Generally, that involves using [PendingIntent.getService()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getService(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)) with an `Intent` pointing to your Service and an action you can using in `onStartCommand()` to distinguish which button was pressed.

Note: make sure you are using [v7.app.NotificationCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html), not the v4 version.

Comment: Got it working! Thanks bud! Didn't even know there was a compat version.